# Can I re-enable Window.alert after override?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, web, browser

If I have a page overriding window.alert box:

```
Window.alert = function() {}
```

can I re-enable the alert box if I have access to the Javascript?

Comment: kind of. you can get/reference the alert method of the window object of an empty, hidden iframe. But that's a hack, not a solution. Why exactly do you need this/what do you need this for?

Comment: This is in case a developer did that assuming it will be safe. However, I wanted to figure out if there is an XSS can an attacker re-activate the Window.alert if he/she controls the portion after the override is performed .

Comment: disable: `window.alert = (str) => console.log("alert:", str);`

injection: `blert = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("iframe")).contentWindow.alert;`

test: `alert("foo"); blert("bar")`

Comment: This is amazing, yes I got it to work. thank you Thomas

Comment: WTG thomas, that's more like what I was thinking, just couldn't get there. Creating an iframe is an excellent way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I would save the original alert function off somewhere else and then reassign it back to it.

```js
var originalAlert = window.alert;

window.alert = function(stuff) {
  console.log('alert invoked');
}

alert(); // displays a message in the console

var newWindow = window.open();

window.alert = newWindow.alert;

newWindow.close();

alert(); // alerts a message
```

I don't know that I would open a new window just to get the alert function, but that function is native code, so once it's been closed over, you can't get it back without some crazy hack like this. At least not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Thank you. what if you only control the portion of code after the override is done?

Comment: You mean like you don't have access to the original alert function?

Comment: correct, I only control the Javascript after the override happened.

Comment: Updated my answer. It's really hacky and probably not production worthy.

Comment: `window.open()` crashes into my browsers popup-blocker.

Comment: Yep...Sorry! I'm no help anymore. I would push back and tell whoever is overriding native code to stop it.